# Showing WiFi signal strengh in Android (show bars)

Tags: android, listview, distance, android-wifi, signal-strength

I´ve made an application to obtain and show relevant wifi information,deleting duplicate SSIDs and showing them by signal strengh (higher RSSI first), also with the RSSI obtained i'm calculating an approximate distance of each AP, i would like to know if there is a way of showing my RSSI on a bar with a color code (Like Wifi Manager App).I'm showing everything in a ListView. Here's my code.

```
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {


        //////////////////// Inicializacion de variables /////////////////////
        final ImageView fondo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fondo);
        ListaWifi = ObjWifi.getScanResults();
        rssi = new int[ListaWifi.size()];
        wifisaux = new String[ListaWifi.size()];
        wifis = new String[ListaWifi.size()];
        BSSID=new String[ListaWifi.size()];
        tam = ListaWifi.size();
        ///////////////// Creacion de Lista de AP /////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i <tam; i++) {

            ////////// Asignacion de canales de acuerdo a frec /////////
            switch (ListaWifi.get(i).frequency) {
                case 2412:
                    canal = 1;
                    break;
                case 2417:
                    canal = 2;
                    break;
                case 2422:
                    canal = 3;
                    break;
                case 2427:
                    canal = 4;
                    break;
                case 2432:
                    canal = 5;
                    break;
                case 2437:
                    canal = 6;
                    break;
                case 2442:
                    canal = 7;
                    break;
                case 2447:
                    canal = 8;
                    break;
                case 2452:
                    canal = 9;
                    break;
                case 2457:
                    canal = 10;
                    break;
                case 2462:
                    canal = 11;
                    break;
            }
            //////////Calculo de la distancia ///////////////////

            dist = Math.pow(10, (-(-26) - (ListaWifi.get(i).level)) / (10 * 21.54));

            /////////////Agregacion de valores en la lista ////////////////
            BSSID[i]=ListaWifi.get(i).BSSID;
            rssi[i] = ListaWifi.get(i).level;
            nombre=BSSID[0];
            wifisaux[i] = (("AP " + (i + 1) + "\n" + "SSID: " + ListaWifi.get(i).SSID + "\n BSSID: " + ListaWifi.get(i).BSSID + "\n Canal: " + canal + "\n RSSI: " + rssi[i] + "dBm" + "\n Distancia: " + dist + " m").toString());

        }

        ///////////////Ordenamiento de AP de acuerdo a potencia///////Ordering list (higher RSSI first)///////
        for (int i = 0; i < tam-1; i++) {
            if (rssi[i] > rssi[i+1]) {
            }else{
                mascerca = wifisaux[i];
                wifisaux[i] = wifisaux[i+1];
                wifisaux[i+1] = mascerca;
                auxbssid=BSSID[i];
                BSSID[i]=BSSID[i+1];
                BSSID[i+1]=auxbssid;
            }
        }
        //////////////Eliminacion de redundancias//////Deleting duplicate SSIDs/////////////////////
        for (int i=0;i<tam;i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < tam; j++) {
                if (BSSID[i].equals(BSSID[j])){
                    wifisaux[i]=wifisaux[j];
                    BSSID[i]=BSSID[j];
                }
            }
            wifis[i] = wifisaux[i];
        }


        ////////////Cambio de imagenes ///////////////////////////////
        nombre=BSSID[0];
        if (nombre.equals(nombre2)){

        }
        else {
            final String str="img_"+(rnd.nextInt(6)+1);
            fondo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",getApplicationContext())));
        }
        nombre2=BSSID[0];

        /////////////Traslado de variables a Lista ////////Show everything in a list//////////////
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested to know how to display icons in the wireless signal.

You can change:

```
////////// Asignacion de canales de acuerdo a frec /////////
        switch (ListaWifi.get(i).frequency) {
            case 2412:
                canal = 1;
                break;
            case 2417:
                canal = 2;
                break;
            case 2422:
                canal = 3;
                break;
            case 2427:
                canal = 4;
                break;
            case 2432:
                canal = 5;
                break;
            case 2437:
                canal = 6;
                break;
            case 2442:
                canal = 7;
                break;
            case 2447:
                canal = 8;
                break;
            case 2452:
                canal = 9;
                break;
            case 2457:
                canal = 10;
                break;
            case 2462:
                canal = 11;
                break;
        }
```

to:

```
    in freq = ListaWifi.get(i).frequency;
    canal = (freq == 2484) ? 14 : ((freq -2407) / 5);
```